# Unexpected output in a basic networking client

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, loops, networking

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class BankClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        String host = "192.168.1.100";
        int port = 7331;

        try(
            Socket bankSocket = new Socket(host, port);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bankSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bankSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fromServer;

            boolean clientRunning = true;
            while(clientRunning) {
                System.out.println("TEST1");
                while((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(fromServer);
                    System.out.println("TEST2");
                }
                System.out.println("TEST3");
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Unknown host " + host);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Disconnected");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm just playing around with networking in Java and this is the script for a basic client, but for some reason I'm getting weird output when I run it with a server:

```
TEST1
Server Message 1
TEST2
Server Message 2
TEST2
```

The program is still running, but the output stops there. The thing that's confusing me is that TEST3 isn't being outputted continuously like I'd expect. It seems like the `while((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)` breaks like it should after two iterations, but nothing after the while loop is running. The `while(clientRunning)` isn't breaking since the program is still running, but it also isn't iterating because TEST3 isn't being outputted. So what's happening here?

Comment: Pass a String(token) such as *STOP* to identify that server has sent all the data and come out of the while loop. There should be a *communication contract* between client and server to talk. `in.readLine()` is a *blocking statement* that waits for next line from the server.

Comment: Presumably the server isn't closing the connection - so the client doesn't know that there won't be more data.

Comment: You are waiting for the server to send another message which blocks your Main thraead

Comment: I understand now, if one of you can put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Seriously, use `java.utils.Scanner` instead of all these buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 but it also isn't iterating because TEST3 isn't being outputted
```

Each time you call the `in.readLine())` you are waiting for the server response to arrive.

Based on your result the server only passed 2 packets of data to the client thus giving you two results and will go back to read the next input stream of the server and will wait for response until the server is closed or when you add a socketTimeout in the Socket of the Client.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `while((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)` your program will wait for an input after it prints `TEST2`. Also, `TEST3` is being outputted outside of the loop, so it will only output when the server stops sending messages, i.e., when `(fromServer = in.readLine()) == null`.

What about you changing this:

```
while((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(fromServer);
    System.out.println("TEST2");
}
```

To something like this:

```
while((fromServer = in.readLine()) != "EXIT") {
    System.out.println(fromServer);
    System.out.println("TEST2");
}
```

Then you can test your code using this test case:

```
TEST1
Server Message 1
TEST2
Server Message 2
TEST2
END
TEST3
```

Also, I highly recommend you to use `java.util.Scanner` to read streams.

Hope I could help.